# How to change the view if I am not present in the viewController class?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code is exectuting but the view is not loading when called form a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720327/code-is-exectuting-but-the-view-is-not-loading-when-called-form-a-function)

I am doing an app with about 6-7 views and their corresponding controllers. I am in a view with a toolbar and button.

When I click this button a popup view comes and my control is being moved to the popup view's Controller. But my view is still the same.

From this popupview Controller's class, I want to change my original view. But since I am not in my original viewControllers class, I am not able to change it.

How can I overcome this? Can anyone plz help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the Popup View as a Subview of the Original ViewController's View, you can access the parent view using superview.

```
UIView *parentView = popupViewController.view.superview;
```

then you can change the parentView as needed.